# Sum of arrays between specific positions in the array

Tags: c#, .net

I have two arrays of doubles. For example: {1,2,3} {4,5,6} We are using (x,y) coordinates as (1,4),(2,5) and (3,6) for example. So there are 3 data points in this example. We need to calculate the slope between all of the points and store the slope with the maximum absolute value. To do this I have a function with a 'for' loop inside a 'for' loop. My code is successfully calculating the maximum absolute value slope when I use it in the Main.

We need to find the positions that this max slope occurs at and print out the corresponding positions in array2. I have done this.

Finally there is a third array. We need to calculate the average value of the numbers up to the first point used in the max slope, the average value of the numbers between the first and second points used in the max slope and also the average value of the numbers from the second point used in the max slope to the end of the array.

Does this needs to be done in the main, or does it need its own method?

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<double> Array1 = new List<double>();
    List<double> Array2 = new List<double>();
    List<double> Array3 = new List<double>();

    Array1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[0]));
    Array2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));
    Array3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));


    int[] positions = GreatestSlopeLocation(Array1, Array2);

    Console.WriteLine("The Location of the max slope is {0} {1}", 
        Array2[positions[0]], Array2[positions[1]]);
}
```

```
static int[] GreatestSlopeLocation(List<double> x, List<double> y)
{
    int size = x.Count;
    double maxSlope = Double.MinValue; // don't set this to 0
    // consider case when all slopes are  negative
    // 
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            double slope = Math.Abs((y[j] - y[i]) / (x[j] - x[i]));
            if (slope > maxSlope) // I think you want > instead of < here
            {
                maxSlope = slope;
                index1 = i;
                index2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[]{index1, index2};
}
```

Comment: I would make a new method that takes the result of `GreatestSlopeLocation` as an argument.  You have to find the position of the max prior to the averages so they are really two different operations.

Comment: I have found the positions of the max successfully but I am having trouble with the averages i.e. finding the average of the numbers given the indexes. Do you mind writing an example?

Comment: Why don't you take it one step at a time? Write a method that takes an array and returns average for that array. And another one that splits your input array into 3 arrays (before, between and after max slope points). With that you can just call 'GetAverage' 3 times with different pieces.